# How to add new tab to admin list of posts and handle result list

Tags: custom-post-types, sort, admin-menu

### [image: Admin links]

The goal is to show posts with special values of custom field (post meta) in separate tab.
I know how to add new tab, here is a code:

```
add_action( 'views_edit-post', 'remove_edit_post_views' );
function remove_edit_post_views( $views ) {
        $views['pre'] = '<a class="'.$class.'" href="'.admin_url().'edit.php?yourlink">Name of Sort</a>';
        return $views;
}
```

but I have no idea how and where I can filter posts.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Admin post queries can be filtered just like frontend queries using `pre_get_posts` and checking for `is_admin`.

```
add_action( 'views_edit-post', 'remove_edit_post_views' );
function remove_edit_post_views( $views ) {
    $views['pre'] = '<a href="'.admin_url().'edit.php?pre=pre">My Special Posts</a>';
    return $views;
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_special_list');

function my_special_list( $q ) {
  $scr = get_current_screen();
  if ( is_admin() && ( $scr->base === 'edit' ) && $q->is_main_query() ) {
    // To target only a post type uncomment following line and adjust post type name
    // if ( $scr->post_type !== 'post' ) return;
    // if you change the link in function above adjust next line accordingly
    $pre = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'pre', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    if ( $pre === 'pre' ) {
      // adjust meta query to fit your needs
      $meta_query = array( 'key' => 'is_special', 'value' => 'yes', );
      $q->set( 'meta_query', array($meta_query) );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That's it!
Hook `pre_get_posts` do the trick!

Comment: hook name is `views_edit-'.$post_type_slug` for custom post types.